# IllegalAnnotationsException: Two classes have the same XML type name

Tags: java, jboss

I am trying to deploy my EAR file on JBoss EAP 6.4.0 without any success. I must add that the same EAR file works perfectly with JBoss WildFly 8.2.1.

My guess is that it has something to do with the interference of JBoss internal JAXB, WS libraries.

See below the error message:

```
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 37 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name

at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:277) [jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:249) [jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:456) [jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656) [jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:347) [cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345) [cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:345) [cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:246) [cxf-core-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:472) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:327) [cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
    ... 41 more

Two classes have the same XML type name
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:106) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.redhat-9.jar:2.2.5.jboss-2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:466) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.redhat-9.jar:2.2.5.jboss-2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:298) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.redhat-9.jar:2.2.5.jboss-2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:141) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.redhat-9.jar:2.2.5.jboss-2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1163) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.redhat-9.jar:2.2.5.jboss-2]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:145) [jaxb-impl-2.2.5.redhat-9.jar:2.2.5.jboss-2]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:262) [jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar:2.2.12]
    ... 51 more
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am generating the CXF client from the WSDL we have received from the customer. When I deploy the EAR on the JBoss WildFly it works without any problems. It has really something todo with JBoss EAP 6.4 itself

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the terms XFD, BBDS and FGM. Sorry for these kind of questions it's new to me.

Comment: Well I can forgive you if you can solve my issue ;p